# How to upload multiple files in one FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I can successfully upload files with the below code using FtpWebRequest.

However, if I upload for example 3 files like below, I want to do that in one request without needing to pass the username and password each time. Because I think I open 3 requests to the server now if I understand correctly?

If that is true. How can the connection stay open all time time and importantly, how can one check if the connections is open before doing the request if one need to pass the username and password again to open a new request?

I know the below line has something to do with this but I don't know how to set up the above scenario entirely correct:

```js
request.KeepAlive = true;
```

Complete code:

```js
        void uploadFilesToFTP()
        {
            List<String> fileLIST = new List<String>();
            fileLIST.Add("C:/ESD/test0.txt");
            fileLIST.Add("C:/ESD/test1.txt");
            fileLIST.Add("C:/ESD/test2.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < fileLIST.Count; i++)
            {
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://someurl.net/folder1/test" + i.ToString() + ".txt");
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.EnableSsl = false;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                request.KeepAlive = true;

                //Read the file's contents into a byte array.
                if (File.Exists(fileLIST[i]))
                {
                    //Write the bytes into the request stream.
                    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileLIST[i]);
                    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                    using (Stream request_stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        request_stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        request_stream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: All connections are handled by the [ServicePointManager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager), which manages the pool of [ServicePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint). A ServicePoint handles the connection to the Host specified in the URL. The ServicePoint will keep the connection alive for a `MaxIdleTime` period. After that, the ServicePoint is *dismissed* and can be recycled. It's not relevant that a FtpWebRequest is initialized with Credentials, this information is already cached and managed by the ServicePoint.

Comment: The initialization method of a FtpWebRequest follows the existing pattern of a WebRequest. How the connection is handled, under the hood, it's unrelated to the class initialization procedure. What matters is the URL of the request and the `FtpWebRequest.Method`. These determine the commands that are sent to the connected server.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the explanation. In this code example with the same .Method will the code establish and open 3 connections or 1 connection?

Comment: One connection. Your code does not create connection, it makes a request. The connection is handled by the ServicePoint.

Comment: Okay, I am not sure why it is one connection. What do I have to change in the code to make it for example 3 connections? Does it bypass the credentials for the 2nd and 3rd file and how does that work?

Comment: If I change folders for the iterating files like this. Will it still be 1 connection or doesn't the folders matter? `"ftp://someurl.net/folder0/test0.txt" and "ftp://someurl.net/folder1/test1.txt"` etc...

Comment: The credentials information is already cached. About the number of connection available per ServicePoint, see [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit). You should use the async version of the WebRequest. See [GetRequestStreamAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststreamasync) and [Stream.WriteAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.writeasync). I'ld avoid `File.ReadAllBytes`. Read the bytes to send with another Stream.

Comment: Is this the line that caches it in ServicePoint 'request.KeepAlive = true;' even that one create a new FtpWebRequest? You are absolutetly right about the `File.ReadAllBytes` this throws an error from time to time. Thank you for this hint there also. Yes I am looking at the URLs now :)

Comment: `KeepAlive = true` is the default behavior. You don't need to set it. You don't really need to worry about the connections; as already mentioned, it's all managed. If you want/need to handle the connection pool directly, there are means to do it. Read the documentation about the `ServicePointManager` and `ServicePoint` classes. Keep in mind that making a Request and creating a Connection are two different things (a WebRequest doesn't necessarily create a new connection).

Comment: Yes okay, that good! `MaxServicePointIdleTime` is 100 seconds and `request.ConnectionGroupName` I can create groupnames from the hostnames to make them unique. Then they would be recycled after 100 seconds which is the default time. Then the requests with the same groupnames will be closed after 100 seconds to not eat up all sockets. Perheps this seems like a good practise. (I perheps have maximum 5 files at a time to upload per groupname)